# Insert a Blank Cell into Every "X"th Row in the Same Column

Tags: r

In an excel file, I have the following table with headers as such:

```
**Date** **Session** **Player** **Pre** **Post** **Distance(m)**
Jan 1         1        Player 1    3        6          1000
Jan 1         1        Player 2    3        7          1500
Jan 1         1        Player 3    4        10         4000
Jan 1         1        Player 4    1        3          600
Jan 2         2        Player 1    2        5          1000
Jan 2         2        Player 2    -        -          1750
Jan 2         2        Player 3    5        5          3000
Jan 2         2        Player 4    3        6          1000
Jan 3         3        Player 1    3        5          2500   
Jan 3         3        Player 2    3        8          1500
Jan 3         3        Player 3    7        7          2500
Jan 3         3        Player 4    -        -            -
```

What am I trying to accomplish is to look at the distance numbers and compare them with the Pre numbers for the following session. So on Session 1 for Player 1, their distance (1000) and their Pre # from Jan 2 (2) should be in the same row.

To do this, after sorting the players by session number, I am trying to find a way to insert an empty cell `-` in the distance column for each player which acts as a placeholder for what would be session 0. This essentially bumps down the distances to match up with the next day's Pre #.

So after performing that on this data set, the result would look like this:

```
**Player**  **Pre for the following Day**             **Distance**
Player 1      3 (S1)                                    -  (Session 0 - Does Not Exist) (This value is inserted)               
Player 1      2 (S2)                                   1000(Session 1)                              
Player 1      3 (S3)                                   1000(Session 2)                                
Player 1      - (S4 - Not included in this example)    2500(Session 3)                       
Player 2      3 (S1)                                   -   (S0)                                      
Player 2      - (S2)                                   1500(S1)                                      
Player 2      3 (S3)                                   1750(S2)                                       
Player 2      - (S4)                                   1500(S3)                                       
Player 3      4 (S1)                                   -   (S0)                                       
Player 3      5 (S2)                                   4000(S1)                                       
Player 3      7 (S3)                                   3000(S2)                                       
Player 3      - (S4)                                   2500(S3)
```

*Player 4 left out for time/redundancy sake*

In this example, session 3 is the last session so the Pre for S4 for all players would just be inserted also as `-` by default.

So a `-` needs to be inserted every 4 rows to match each distance and the correct player, and after the last session, create a new row for each player giving `-` for Pre and Post, and the correct distance.

In my attempt to do this, I have the following code and dataset:
From dput()

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 1577836800, 
1577836800, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1578009600, 
1578009600, 1578009600, 1578009600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Session = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), Player = c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", 
"Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 1", "Player 2", 
"Player 3", "Player 4"), Pre = c("3", "3", "4", "1", "2", "-", 
"5", "3", "3", "3", "7", "-"), Post = c("6", "7", "10", "3", 
"5", "-", "5", "6", "5", "8", "7", "-"), Distance = c("1000", 
"1500", "4000", "600", "1000", "1750", "3000", "1000", "-", "1500", 
"2500", "-")), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

and my code:

```
test1 <- data.frame("2020-01-01",1,"Player 1",3,6, "-")
test2 <- data.frame("2020-01-01",4,"Player 1","-","-","2500")
names(test1) <- c("Date", "Session", "Player", "Pre", "Post", "Distance")
names(test2) <- c("Date", "Session", "Player", "Pre", "Post", "Distance")
new <- rbind(test1, stackEX) #This puts the new row at the top where I want it
                             #Not sure why this removes dates for other rows though
new <- rbind(new, test2)#This is for Session 4 which does not exist in this example
```

But using this way does not insert a `-` cell in the distance column to bump the values down, and instead I am only aware of how to add an *entire* new row rather than one *cell*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by joining with a complete set of `Player` / `Session` combinations and by shifting `Distance`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[CJ(Player, Session = 1:4, unique = TRUE), on = .(Player, Session)][
  , Distance := shift(Distance)][]

          Date Session   Player  Pre Post Distance
 1: 2020-01-01       1 Player 1    3    6     <NA>
 2: 2020-01-02       2 Player 1    2    5     1000
 3: 2020-01-03       3 Player 1    3    5     1000
 4:       <NA>       4 Player 1 <NA> <NA>     2500
 5: 2020-01-01       1 Player 2    3    7     <NA>
 6: 2020-01-02       2 Player 2    -    -     1500
 7: 2020-01-03       3 Player 2    3    8     1750
 8:       <NA>       4 Player 2 <NA> <NA>     1500
 9: 2020-01-01       1 Player 3    4   10     <NA>
10: 2020-01-02       2 Player 3    5    5     4000
11: 2020-01-03       3 Player 3    7    7     3000
12:       <NA>       4 Player 3 <NA> <NA>     2500
13: 2020-01-01       1 Player 4    1    3     <NA>
14: 2020-01-02       2 Player 4    3    6      600
15: 2020-01-03       3 Player 4    -    -     1000
16:       <NA>       4 Player 4 <NA> <NA>        -
```

The *cross join* expression

```
CJ(Player, Session = 1:4, unique = TRUE)
```

returns all `Player` / `Session` combos:

> ```
>       Player Session
>  1: Player 1       1
>  2: Player 1       2
>  3: Player 1       3
>  4: Player 1       4
>  5: Player 2       1
>  6: Player 2       2
>  7: Player 2       3
>  8: Player 2       4
>  9: Player 3       1
> 10: Player 3       2
> 11: Player 3       3
> 12: Player 3       4
> 13: Player 4       1
> 14: Player 4       2
> 15: Player 4       3
> 16: Player 4       4
> ```

The default arguments of `shift()` are sufficient here: `shift(Distance)` *lags* `Distance` *by one* and `NA` is used for *filling*, i.e., the values in the `Distance` column are moved down to the next row. So row 4 (Session 4) for `Player 1` gets the `Distance` value of the previous row (Session 3) as requested. The empty row at the top becomes `NA`. See also `help("shift", "data.table")`.

Note that we do *not* need to group here because the whole column is lagged.

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 1577836800, 
1577836800, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1577923200, 1578009600, 
1578009600, 1578009600, 1578009600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Session = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), Player = c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", 
"Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 1", "Player 2", 
"Player 3", "Player 4"), Pre = c("3", "3", "4", "1", "2", "-", 
"5", "3", "3", "3", "7", "-"), Post = c("6", "7", "10", "3", 
"5", "-", "5", "6", "5", "8", "7", "-"), Distance = c("1000", 
"1500", "4000", "600", "1000", "1750", "3000", "1000", "2500", 
"1500", "2500", "-")), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: After updating your code with mine, I do have 2 quick questions about yours.1st, in this part ```CJ(Player, Session = 1:84, unique = TRUE)```, what is the ```unique``` referring to? Is it unique sessions?Because there shoud never be duplicate session #s for anyone, but there are times in my code where there are multiple sessions on the same day, but since Date is not called anywhere in your code, I am confused about that.2nd question: for ```Distance := shift(Distance)``` how does this know to shift everything down by 1? Because distance doesn't = 1, so would you also be able to explain that?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized you explained what the cross join expression already does, so it is the unique combinations between players and sessions... but still not understanding the shifting part for the distance. Thanks!

Comment: @samrizz4, I have added more explanations concerning the `shift()` function.

Comment: That makes everything much more clear to me - thanks again for the help.